# How to create an if statement to ask an summation with an or in it

Tags: swift, if-statement, xcode6

i want to ask the computer to compute

```
if 1 or 2 + 2 or 3 + 4 or 5 == 6{
  // do this
  }
```

and it would go through the combinations and find between the first numbers it would be 1 then 2 then 3 and that would equal 6 how could i do this in code?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Add more details or code you've tried.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you have multiple variables that you want compared, to see if any of them equal to 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the question you're trying to ask is: Given lists `[1,2]`, `[2,3]` and `[3,4]`, what combinations of these values sum to be 6. If so, you just want to sum them and check.

```
let xs = [1,2]
let ys = [2,3]
let zs = [3,4]

func combine<T,U,V>(xs: [T], ys:[U], zs:[V]) -> [(T,U,V)] {
    var result = [(T,U,V)]()
    for x in xs {
        for y in ys {
            for z in zs {
                result.append(x,y,z)
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}

let combinations = combine(xs, ys, zs)
    .filter { (x, y, z) in (x + y + z) == 6 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what you are tying to do, but here is my best guess based on your latest comment.

Given a list of expressions , do any of them equal 6?

```
let expressions = [ 1, 2 + 2, 3 + 4, 5, 6 ]
for expression in expressions {
  if expression == 6 {
    println("found the number 6!")
    break
  }  
}
```

The above will print "found the number 6!" if any of the expressions equal 6,  in this example the last entry in the array is 6 so it will print "found the number 6!"